# CSS not loading in Heroku, working in local foreman

Tags: heroku

I am using a angular app which is working fine locally, using

```
foreman start -p 9000 web
```

also using

```
grunt serve
```

when deploying to heroic, I am getting errors on missing css files. One example

```
https://rc-batchentry-dev.herokuapp.com/components/batch-review.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using grunt build tool.

web.js (relevant section)

```
// Static files
if (/development/.test(app.get('env'))) {
    console.log('ENVIRONMENT: development');
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/.tmp'));
    app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
}
if (/production/.test(app.get('env'))) {
    console.log('ENVIRONMENT: production');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
}
// Start the server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 9000, function () {
    console.log('App started:', app.get('env'));
});
```

index.html
css section only:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-delete.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-design.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-edit.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-import.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-review.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-revisions.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batch-view.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/batches.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/monitor.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/unsupported.css"></link>
```

Comment: It is not heroic, it is heroku, apologize must be auto correction.

Answer (score 1):

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production`

The above environment setting resolved it, when I looked at the heroku logs it was pointing to development.